# Javascript to parse json object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse the following (validated) json string using javascript.  I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**code:**

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.Design_Lump_Sum[1]);
alert(obj[1]);
```

**json object:**

```
     {
    "Capex_Lump_Sum": 
    {
    "Pipework and associated fittings": "86086.9",
    "Cable Trays": "10410.4",
    "New Mechanical Services Switchboard": "23209.28",
    "Decommissioning removal of Redundant Mechanical Plant": "28342.32",
    "Electrical system labelling": "473.2",
    "Handover Documentation": "2957.5",
    "Mechanical system labelling": "946.4",
    "Service and Maintenance during DL": "16196.46",
    "Painting": "9227.4",
    "Submain Cabling": "27471.63",
    "Construction Works": "17464.63",
    "Decommissioning removal of redundant mech electrical plant": "5323.5",
    "Framed AsBuilt Drawings": "591.5",
    "Pre Post Air Balancing": "10883.6",
    "Innotech DDC controls and associated cabling": "23831.54",
    "LSL": "2663.0",
    "Testing and Commissioning": "4519.06",
    "Temporary air conditioning": "87243.88",
    "Supply and installation of Air Handling Units Condensor Units": "194521.85",
    "133.0": "105.0",
    "Ductwork Dampers Louvres": "96018.19",
    "Building certifier": "7038.85",
    "Facility Manager Training": "1183.0",
    "AMS": "5915.0",
    "Pre Post Site Acoustic Testing": "5867.68",
    "Penetrations and Fire Sealing": "3903.9"
    },

    "Design_Lump_Sum": 
    {
    "Electrical Services Design": "6915.82",
    "Mechanical Services Design": "13569.01"
    }, 

    "Opex_Lump_Sum": 
    {"Testing and Commissioning": "1200.0"}
}
```

Comment: `obj.Design_Lump_Sum` is an Object, not an Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is already a **valid JSON**, you don't need to parse it. Just remove the line - `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` and access your object directly as - `obj.Design_Lump_Sum['Electrical Services Design']`

Comment: Nice, since the data is unknown, how am i abe to store each line from each 3 sections into a variable

Comment: sorry, but how could i for example only get the "Design_Lump_Sum" items

Comment: You can get the keys like this - `var keys = Object.keys(obj.Design_Lump_Sum);`

Comment: wow,thanks. how would i be able to iterate through var keys1 = Object.keys(obj.Capex_Lump_Sum); and store in variables.

Comment: for (var asset in keys1) {
           if (keys1.hasOwnProperty(asset)) {
            console.log(asset + " -> " + keys1[asset]);
           }
          }